# Not getting "-" (minus sign) in math mode, procedure \linebreak is not working with "algorithmic" env

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmic

```
\begin{algorithmic}
        \Procedure{$M_{topo}$}{$f^-,y$} \inebreak
            $(n, m, q, A,B)\leftarrowff^-, y_1...y_m\leftarrow y$
            \For {$(g, i, j) \in \{n + 1, . . . , n + q\} × \{0, 1\} × \{0, 1\}$}
                \If{$g  \leq n + q − m$} $G_g(i, j) \leftarrow 0$
                \Else $G_g(i, j)\leftarrow y_{\text{g−(n+q−m)}}$
                \EndIf
            \EndFor
            $f \leftarrow (n, m, q, A,B,G), x \leftarrow 0^n$ k
            \Return (f, x)
        \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic} \\
```

Not getting `$(n, m, q, A,B)\leftarrowff^-, y_1...y_m\leftarrow y$` on second line after using `\linebreak`

And `-` sign is not getting in `\Else $G_g(i, j)\leftarrow y_{\text{g−(n+q−m)}}$`

[image]

Comment: I assume `\inebreak` is a typo; you meant `\linebreak`, right? Similarly, I take it that `\leftarrowff^-` should be `\leftarrow f^-`.

Answer (score 1):

- In an `algorithmicx` environment, newlines are generate via the `\State` keyword, not via `\linebreak`.
- Don't use non-ASCII unicode glyphs such as `×` and `−`, unless you use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and a suitable unicode math font. Instead, use `\times` and `-`; the latter is the plain-ASCII "dash" character.
- Also, type `\dots` and not "`...`".

A full MWE; note the "sudden" [!] appearance of **end if** and **end for**:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
        \Procedure{$M_{\mathrm{topo}}$}{$f^-,y$} 
            \State $(n, m, q, A,B)\gets f^-,\ y_1,\dots, y_m\gets y$
            \For {$(g, i, j) \in \{n+1,\dots,n+q\} \times \{0, 1\} \times \{0, 1\}$}
                \If {$g  \leq n + q - m$} $G_g(i, j) \gets 0$
                \Else \ $G_g(i, j)\gets y_{g-(n+q-m)}$
                \EndIf
            \EndFor
            \State $f \gets (n, m, q, A,B,G),\ x \gets 0^n$ k % huh?
            \State \textbf{return} $(f, x)$
        \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Observe that I've replaced all instances of `\leftarrow` with `\gets`, mainly to shorten the code.